# mat-autocomplete input element shows [object object] on component initialize

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

```
     HTML:
<form [formGroup]="basicForm">
    <section>
    <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Select Country*</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="text" maxlength="20" formControlName="country [matAutocomplete]="auto">
                <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="countryDisplayWith">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let country of filteredCountryAutoCompleteOptions | async [value]="country">
                        {{country}}</mat-option>
                </mat-autocomplete>
            </mat-form-field>
</section>
</form>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
TS:

filteredCountry: string[] = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];

this.basicForm = new FormGroup({
      country: new FormControl({ value: '' }, Validators.required) });

filteredCountryAutoCompleteOptions: Observable<string[]> | undefined;
  countryDynamicFilter() {
    this.filteredCountryAutoCompleteOptions = this.basicForm.controls.country.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map((value) => this._filter(value))
    );
  }
  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.filteredCountry.filter(
      (option) =>
        option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
    );
  }
  countryDisplayWith(op: any) {
    return op ? op: '';
  }
```

I am getting [Object Object] initially in Input Box as a value, But autocomplete works fine.

I believe this is something to do with [displayWith]. need help to figure this out..

Comment: For `<mat-option>` element, instead of displaying as `{{ country }}` which `country` is an object, you can display the name as `{{ country.name }}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .component.html

Modify the `<mat-option>` element to display string for example `{{country.name}}` instead of `{{country}}` as `country` is an object.

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="countryDisplayWith">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let country of filteredCountryAutoCompleteOptions | async" [value]="country">
    {{ country.name }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

And altering the function for `[displayWith]` to display the `country.name` instead of `country`.

> .component.ts

```js
countryDisplayWith(op: any) {
  return op ? op.name : '';
}
```

---

### References

[Setting separate control and display values](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#setting-separate-control-and-display-values)

Comment: Hi Yong Shun,

It worked! 
by setting source as object..

also I had to remove
 ////  { value: '' }, Validators.required   ////
from
////  country: new FormControl({ value: '' }, Validators.required) });  ////